# How do I Clear the discord rich presence in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, discord

When I close the game I want the discord rich presence to clear but it still show that I'm playing the game, this my discord controller:

```
using Discord;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DiscordController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public long applicationID;
    [Space]
    public string details = "Walking around the world";
    public string state = "Current velocity: ";
    [Space]
    public string largeImage = "game_logo";
    public string largeText = "Discord Tutorial";
    private long time;

    private static bool instanceExists;
    public Discord.Discord discord;

    Scene scene;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Transition the GameObject between scenes, destroy any duplicates
        if (!instanceExists)
        {
            instanceExists = true;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if (FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Log in with the Application ID
        discord = new Discord.Discord(applicationID, (System.UInt64)Discord.CreateFlags.NoRequireDiscord);

        time = System.DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

        UpdateStatus();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        // Destroy the GameObject if Discord isn't running
        try
        {
            discord.RunCallbacks();
        }
        catch
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        UpdateStatus();
    }

    void UpdateStatus()
    {
        // Update Status every frame
        try
        {
            var activityManager = discord.GetActivityManager();
            var activity = new Discord.Activity
            {
                Details = details,
                State = state + scene.name,
                Assets =
                {
                    LargeImage = largeImage,
                    LargeText = largeText
                },
                Timestamps =
                {
                    Start = time
                }
            };

            activityManager.UpdateActivity(activity, (res) =>
            {
                if (res != Discord.Result.Ok) Debug.LogWarning("Failed connecting to Discord!");
            });

        }
        catch
        {
            // If updating the status fails, Destroy the GameObject
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

After I leave the game it still shows that I'm playing and I couldn't fin anything on youtube about it
Please help me to resolve this issue, I've tried myself but I couldn't fix it
[Discord Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAEcn.png)

Comment: Looks like there's a `ClearActivity` function. https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/activities

Answer (score 0):

You can use `activityManager.ClearActivity()` that can be found in the ActivityManager.
This method will return a Discord.Result via callback

Example:

```
activityManager.ClearActivity((result) =>
{
    if (result == Discord.Result.Ok)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
    }
});
```

More information on this topic can be found [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/activities#clearactivity).